# Is there a central repository for time zone information

Tags: time, timezone

I know that systems are using their own time zone databases at different levels.

Is there a central place where all timezeone and DST information lives, that makes it easy for programmers to write updates to their time zone data sources?

For example, do people make provisions for a time zone for each possible combination? For example, islands in Mexican territory don't follow DST, so they would each have to be different from the three mainland time zones (that should be described w/ DST date ranges).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best database I know of is the [tz database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm), also known as the Olson database.

Comment: These days, the data is now hosted by IANA.  See https://iana.org/time-zones and ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tz-link.html (yes, `ftp`; yes, `.html` and not `.htm`).

Answer (score 1):

Get the time zone database from ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases — was ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub — or the many other source on the web. These will be keyed in UN ISO codes and English country/City names

And then translate them from http://www.unicode.org/cldr/

e.g.

- French   http://unicode.org/cldr/data/common/main/fr.xml
- Spanish  http://unicode.org/cldr/data/common/main/es.xml