# I need a mapping list of cities to timezones- best way to get it?

Tags: timezone

I have a list of cities, states/provinces, and countries and I need to find their respective timezones easily. Specifically, I need to know which Windows TimeZone they map to.  So far this has been a difficult process, because there's no easy way to pass a city to something and get a timezone back (a timezone being an offset and whether or not the timezone supports Daylight Savings Time).

The current flow is to use http://www.batchgeocode.com to get the latitude/longitude of the city (which really calls a Yahoo service) and then call http://www.EarthTools.org to get a timezone letter, which maps to an offset.  The problem is the yahoo service will sometimes return a bad longitude/latitude, and earthtools.org doesn't know a lot about DST info so mapping to the correct TimeZone Id is a tedious manual process.

I can't be the first person who has done this- does anybody know of a better way, or some list out there which has the info I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what is the issue with the Lat/Lon?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Interesting question! These other three SO posts ([41504](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude), [55901](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city) and [237023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237023/is-there-a-central-repository-for-timezone-information)) mention a couple of leads. There's the [Olson database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (see the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo) for description), but it looks more algorithmic/programmatic (e.g. if you know a county name, there's a rule for it for certain counties in [Indiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana)).

I tried looking at EarthTools but it [failed](http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/46.76667/-56.18333) for [St.Pierre/Miquelon](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=46.76667,+-56.18333&t=h&z=11&iwloc=addr), one of the good test cases (-3:00 rather the -3:30 for nearby Newfoundland which is what EarthTools says).

Some promising options: [worldtimeengine.com](http://worldtimeengine.com/) has a free interactive version and an API which appears to be inexpensive (5000 queries per British pound), but the API only covers lat,long queries as inputs (not location as input, which is something the interactive version has).

**Best lead:** I'd look at [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) which looks like it has a nice rich API that you could use, and they have both a free (slow) version, and a commercial version for better performance.

p.s. here are some good test cases (from [worldtimezone.com](http://www.worldtimezone.com/faq.html) and [Wikipedia's list of timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones), the [map of time zones](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Timezones2008.png) is also illustrative):

- Caracas, Venezuela (-4:30)
- Gander, Newfoundland (-3:30)
- Tehran, Iran (+3:30)
- Kabul, Afghanistan (+4:30)
- Kathmandu, Nepal (+5:45)
- Yangon, Myanmar (+6:30)
- Chatham islands, New Zealand (+12:45)
- Easter Island (-6)
- St. Pierre and Miquelon (-3)
- Stanley, Falkland Islands (-4)
- Evansville, Indiana (-6=Central)
- Ontario, Oregon (-7=Mountain)

Comment: geonames.org provides a data dump (by country) of all known cities and their Olson timezone. Hands down the best way to do it. http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: See also [this community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)

Comment: @skylarsutton seconded. It's pretty simple to load geonames' data into a SQL table and slice it any which way.

Answer (score 3):

[moment-timezone](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone) is a JavaScript library for timezone calculations.

All their timezone data linking countries, timezomes and offsets is all [available in json format](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/bf1de5d6a7cc6cb493d90b021fb2c0ac777c93eb/data).

Comment: Worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

We use **.NET C# MVC** and we needed a list of **Windows Timezone** for Each country.

So that for every registering user we could set the timezone automatically.

Most online databases provide **IANA** timezones and it's difficult to map to a specific country.

Using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) we managed to create a Json which lists the following entries.

```
CountryName
2LetterIsoCountryCode
3LetterIsoCountryCode
IANATimezones
WindowsTimezones
```

You can download the generated [JSON here](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/atleu/countries_with_timeZones.json).

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the 2nd part of your current workflow.  I've written a Java library which maps lat/long's to timezones, where the database is encoded in the source code.

The source code is basically an enormous tree of if statements:  if (lat >= -33.0) if (lng < -151.5) ... else ... and so on.  It's just a single class. So if you use C# it would be trivial to port it.

http://www.edval.biz/mapping-lat-lng-s-to-timezones

It's accurate to 22km.

Comment: I hope you plan on updating the source code every time a government decides to update time zones.

Comment: How often does that occur?

Comment: Pretty darn frequently. http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/

Comment: My source code is only affected by (lat,lng) --> TimeZone mapping changes, not DST changes.  Since Jan 2012 I see Crimea changing, and a few proposals to change timezones, and a timezone change in Antarctica, but nothing else.  But I admit is in an issue.