# Get timezone by state/province and country?

Tags: c#, timezone, region

Does anyone know how to get the timezone based on a users state/province and country selection?

Comment: Is this for a windows app or a web app?

Comment: web app. My user sets their region, country etc and i need to grab the correct time zone for that location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need a mapping list of cities to timezones- best way to get it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262264/i-need-a-mapping-list-of-cities-to-timezones-best-way-to-get-it)

Comment: Uuuummm, how is it "difficult to tell what is being asked here"??

Comment: I think i was pretty clear... I need a users timezone based on there region and country...

Comment: I think the only way to really do this is a database of all the countries with their states or provinces and what time zone they're in.  So this really isn't a programming question, it's more of a "where do I get this data" question (there's a few suggestions listed already)..  Most websites just have users select their timezone from a dropdown list, anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: I disagree with closing the question as "not a real question", but I do think it's a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the public time zone database **[tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)**

Here is an example for C# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Using_time_zones_in_NET.aspx

```
// Get the local computer's time zone
TzTimeZone zone = TzTimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

// Get a common time zone
zone = TzTimeZone.ZoneUsEastern;

// Get a zone in the time zone database
zone = TzTimeZone.GetTimeZone(TzConstants.TimezoneEuropeMoscow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at http://www.geonames.org/ - they provide a number of RESTful web services for geo-location and the like.  You'd likely have to use one of their services to get a lat/lon for the state/province, then the actual timezone service (which gives the timezone at a given lat/lon).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a web app, you won't be able to use `TimeZoneInfo` or any of the built in utilities. I would look into using a service of some sort, like Yahoo Web Services API or the Google Maps API.