# ColdFusion 7/8 Varied Timezones

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-7

This problem makes me really sad. I'm working with a pretty archaic web application with an eclectic mix of programming languages. Previously, it stored any and all datetimes in a Datetime field in our MySQL database. Until now, everything has been done in server time, which happens to be US/Pacific. I was tasked with adding "Timezone functionality" to the application. I have been pretty successful with converting most of the application.

My only remaining problems are the use of ColdFusion specific datetime [functions](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000357.htm). There appears to be many lines of code that use some of these functions. My ideal situation would be to be able to adjust the timezone on my Application.cfm page and not need to worry about the timezone for any of these functions. I've done quite a bit of searching and I can't seem to find anything. Any help would be awesome! Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: "many lines of code that use some of these functions"? that's expected.

Comment: I wasn't implying that it shouldn't be that way, just that changing line by line would be pretty rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: [How to handle timezones in CFML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795615/how-to-handle-timezones-in-cfml)